# Add waiting time to android asynchronous task

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a Forgot Password screen. The user fills in his email, clicks on submit and an HTML request is submitted. It either returns the string "true" or "false". If it returns true, I would change the text on the screen, wait for 2 seconds and send the user to another page. Here's how I'm doing it

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if ("true".equals(response)) {

                //make one TextView invisible and the other visible.
                findViewById(R.id.pre_password_reset_text).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
                findViewById(R.id.post_password_reset_text).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace;
                }
                startActivity(new Intent(ForgotPassword.this, Login.class));  

            } else {
                //show error message
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //show error message
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

The problem is, the thread goes to sleep for 2 seconds and after that the text-change happens. But, in the code I've written the text-change to happen first and then `Thread.sleep`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You change the visibility of your textview, then wait 2 seconds. And now you ask why the visibility change doesn't happen after the delay?

Comment: Thankyou, my bad I wasn't aware of that. Now I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Volley, the onResponse() code is called from the main thread, so calling Thread.sleep is definitelly forbidden because it would block the UI.

If you want to delay the call to the next activity, you need to defer it to a runnable, and [delay](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) it :

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    if ("true".equals(response)) {

        //make one TextView invisible and the other visible.
        TextView passwordView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pre_password_reset_text).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.post_password_reset_text).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        passwordView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(ForgotPassword.this, Login.class));
            }
        }, 2000);

    } else {
        //show error message
    }
}
```

A cleaner way would be to create a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) in your Activity/Fragment and post the runnable on it, but it is simpler to directly use your password view.

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.sleep` in main thread of your app isn't a good idea. You could use Android handlers to schedule a task in the future. Handlers will behave in an  asynchronous message passing manner, so you don't freeze up your whole app during the wait period.

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
          // Start your new activity here!
    }
}, 2000);
```

**Note:** All views and their derivations come with a built-in handler, so you wouldn't need to define a bare handler for this purpose.